# JSF Action Listener - dual behavior

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I am using the Apache MyFaces flavor of JSFs and I'm experiencing some odd behavior with the Action Listener.

When I use a global `action-listener` like this:

```
 <application>
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
  <el-resolver id="msgSrcResolver">com.personal.framework.utils.FacesELResolver</el-resolver>
  <message-bundle>resources.errors</message-bundle>
  <action-listener>com.personal.framework.listeners.MyActionListener</action-listener>
 </application>
```

the JSFs worked well.  The 'MyActionListener.processAction(..)' method worked by calling the `action` method listed on the `CommandButton`.  Unfortunately, we cannot use this due to some conflicts brought up in a Spring WebFlow-based application within the same project.

To fix this, I have tried to add the Action Listener directly to the `CommandButton` like so:

```
<h:commandButton id="continue" forceId="true"
image="continue.gif"
action="#{depositBean.postProcess}"
value="Continue"> 
<f:actionListener type="com.personal.framework.listeners.MyActionListener" > </f:actionListener>
</h:commandButton>
```

This method of using the `ActionListener` does not work as expected - it will call the `depositBean.postProcess` through `MyActionListener` as I want, but then `depositBean.postProcess` is called again, outside of MyActionListeren.

How can I use the `ActionListener` in the `CommandButton` without having the `Action` called the second time, by itself (in the same way as when using a global `ActionListener`)?

Note - we use the `ActionListener` for validation error handling so all `Action` methods must be called through the `ActionListener`.

Comment: So, the problems occurred after adding Spring Web Flow to the application?

Comment: @BalusC - no, the Web Flow was there already.  Our pages still work but that one `action-listener` line in the faces-config.xml file intercept the Web Flow actions. Other people are looking into trying to fix the configuration but it's out of my breadth of knowledge so I am working on the backup plan (which is to remove the global listener and add it to each element as needed).